# how to clear local cost map?

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use sonar-layer in my local cost map, but I cant clear the layer.

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /odom
  robot_base_frame: /base_footprint
  update_frequency: 10.0
  publish_frequency: 0.5
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 3.5
  height: 3.5
  resolution: 0.05
  transform_tolerance: 1.0

  plugins:
    - {name: static_map,      type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
#- {name: obstacles,       type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: sonar,           type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
  sonar:
    topics: ['/sonar_0', '/sonar_1','/sonar_2', '/sonar_3', '/sonar_4', '/sonar_6', '/sonar_7', '/sonar_8', '/sonar_9', '/sonar_10', '/sonar_11']  
    no_readings_timeout: 0.0
    clear_threshold: 0.0
  inflation_layer:
    inflation_radius: 0.10
```

when obstacle , sonar-layer cant clear the obstacle.
My robot cant move.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278296/how-to-clear-local-cost-map?/) by [wings0728](https://answers.ros.org/users/32538/wings0728/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2017-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did you try

`rosservice call /move_base/clear_costmaps "{}"` ?

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-04-06**:
Hi, does this clear both costmaps? Or only the local costmap?
I think even if it clears both, the global costmap upon reinflation would be identical to previous one, so effectively only the local costmap would be reset. Do you think this is true?